# Nesting dictionaries with a for loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to add a dictionary within a dictionary in the current code like this!

```
    i = 0
    A ={}
    x = [...]
    for i in x:
        (a,b) = func(x)#this returns two different Dictionaries as a and b 
          for key in a.keys():
            A[key] = {}
            A[key][i] = a[key]
        print('A:',A)
```

as I executed it, I am getting 'A' dictionary being printed throughout the loop! But, i need them in one single dictionary say: "C" 
How do I do that?

Comment: please post the code of the function that is returning the dictionaries

Comment: the function has a list of x. Sorry, I cudn't post the entire function. x is a list for each item in that list, the function returns two dictionary values for every iterations.

Comment: `for i in x:` is not valid if `x == 35`; please post valid code, or better yet, post what `func(x)` returns and what `A` is supposed to look like in the end.

Comment: x is a list with length 35, not the value. a,b are two different dictionaries. A = {a.key:{x:a.value}, , , ,.....}

Comment: They why did you write `x = 35`? The length is irrelevant; `x = [...]` would have been sufficient for an example. Don't make us guess what your code *really* looks like by posting nonsensical examples.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: thanks, I am sorry. I am new here. hope now, it makes sense.